# why is a reference to window.parent better than window.parent in a closure?

Tags: javascript, closures, subdomain

outer.html hosted on `www.blah.com`:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    (function(){
        var doc,where,iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        where = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        where.parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, where);

        doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        doc.open()._l = function() {
                var js = this.createElement("script");
                js.src = "inner.js";
                this.body.appendChild(js);
        };

        doc.write('<body onload="document._l();">');
        doc.close();
    })();

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log("outer: was " + document.domain);
        document.domain = "blah.com";
        console.log("outer: is " + document.domain);
    }, 500);
    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

inner.js is as follows:

```
(function(w){
    w = window.parent;
    function test() {
        try {
            console.log("try:" + window.parent.document.domain);
        }
        catch (e){
            console.log("catch:" + w.document.domain);
        }
    }

    test();
    //document.domain of hosting page (parent) changes in between these calls
    setTimeout(test, 1000);
})(window);
```

Notice that in between calls to `test()`, `document.domain` in the hosting window is changed to `blah.com`.

The first call to `test()`, of course, prints: 
`try:www.blah.com`

The second call to `test()` is the issue.

In Chrome, I see:
`try:blah.com`, which makes sense.

In IE11 & IE10, I see:
`catch:blah.com`

So, `window.parent.document.domain` failed, but `w.document.domain` worked, even though `window.parent === w`.

Why is that?

Comment: You'll need to provide an [MCVE](/help/mcve). Working from an outline of what you're doing is going to lead to people doing things *differently* from what you're actually doing. It makes more sense just to post two **minimal**, complete HTML files -- one for the hosting window, one for the frame. For instance, when I tried, I got a different result on Chrome than what you describe (a `SecurityError`, which wasn't caught).

Comment: This looks a lot like an IE11 bug.